# Aggregate stock return predictive panel analysis

Tags: bootstrap, panel-data

I am trying to run a panel OLS predictive regression on stock returns for 7 countries using 8 macro economic variables. I have already done the simple linear regression analysis that has highlighted the presence or absence of predictive power for each variable per country, and i am aware of the various problems of sample bias and data mining, which can be addressed with a robust bootstrap procedure.

However, I have been advised to run a panel analysis to look for a common break date in the data accross countries, and i would appreciate advise on how to go about this. I have run the pooled OLS regression and i went further to run the Fixed effects regression, which has increased the standard errors a bit and both tests confirm the individual predictive ability of the same variables (interest rate, tbills and business confidence index) as the earlier simple linear regression.

My main problem is how to go about identifying these breaks both in the simple OLS and Panel OLS. My understanding is that if there are breaks then an out of sample technique would allow the parameters in the predictive regression to vary over time.

I am not so great statistically, but any pointers in the right direction would be highly appreciated

Comment: Chow test is the most common technique for detecting structural breaks in linear regression. There might be better techniques for panel data, but to start you can just split the data up and estimate the model on each half and see if the coefficients are different.